# iOS-UIButton custom target

Tags: ios, uibutton, selector, objective-c-blocks

I add UIButton programmatically (`self.button` is my property `UIButton`):

```
self.button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(139, 366, 42, 34)];
[self.button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:completion:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

I call programmatically to the button target and also I want the framework to invoke the target when the user push the button.

The target selector is:

```
-(void)buttonPressed:(UIButton*)sender completion:(void (^)())completionBlock;
```

The second argument is a block.

When I try to introspection/invoke the block I get an exception `EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x0)`
I know that I try to invoke `UITouchesEvent` because of the framework target action.

How can I make custom target with completion block?

Comment: sorry but i don't understand what block you want to pass...where is this block to pass?

Comment: It doesn't matter which block I m trying to pass, What's matter is the core of the question, How can i make a target of UIButton with completion block?

Comment: i ask this just to understand the situation, but if is the core, i reply you below ;)

Comment: i don't down vote. I reply below, read my complete example.

Comment: @MatteoGobbi Thanks man! someone else down vote me, I asked him why..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You **can't pass a completion block** there, but you can make something like this:

```
self.button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(139, 366, 42, 34)];
[self.button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

-(void)buttonPressed:(UIButton*)sender {
    [self buttonPressed:sender completion:^{
        //something
    }];
}

-(void)buttonPressed:(UIButton*)sender completion:(void (^)())completionBlock {
    //do something

    //invoke block
    completionBlock();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can't**.  For the button action, system expect to have a single parameter and that too is the `sender`(Invoker of the action method) ie the `UIButton` instance itself. If you want to do anything with a second argument i would suggest you to have a wrapper some thing like

```
-(void)buttonPressed:(UIButton*)sender
{
 [self customMethodWithcompletion:^{

}];
}
```

Inside the  `customMethodWithcompletion` you can perform your operations.

Answer (score 0):

A [target-action listener for UIKit](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/Target-Action/Target-Action.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010810-CH12-SW44) must have one of the following three signatures:

```
- (void)action
- (void)action:(id)sender
- (void)action:(id)sender forEvent:(UIEvent *)event
```

If there is a first parameter, the "sender" control (the control that you are listening to actions for) will be passed to it. If there is furthermore a second parameter, the UIEvent object will be passed to it. You don't have any control over what is passed to the method.

There are many third-party libraries that implement a Block-based API for UIControls that you can find on the Internet. Essentially what they do is attach the completion block as an associative object to the control, and retrieve it in the handling method.